# How to allow every admin access except viewing and editing a single directory?

Tags: administration, access-control, capabilities

We have some servers running our web application as well as nginx, redis and a few other services. I want to grant access to these servers to a system administrator to manage these systems, but I want to deny access to the directory containing application secrets (like database password) and code (so that he can not change code to report passwords). In fact, I want to grant access to manage the system but refuse access to data.

Is this possible? I think it should be using Linux capabilities, but I don't know how.

Is it safe? How we can improve safety? (I think he may get access to these files by changing nginx configs, or by exploiting redis vulnerabilities).

Comment: Can you encrypt the data you don't want to give access to? I suspect that will be the only way since anything else you do, he can undo once you give him root access.

Comment: As our code is also on this server and needs the credentials to operate i need something that can separate that from the admin. The first thing that came to my mind was to give the admin not the root but some kind of restricted root access with another account. this account should for instance have access to change the nginx conf, query the redis server, manage resource usage etc. but can not access the sensitve user data. It seems that 'capabilities' can help but it is too complicated.

Comment: Just not keeping the directory in such system? But so the question: who will use such database? If a program can read it, also admins can read it. (You may be able to restrict permissions to admin, but it will be difficult, and probably there will be way to bypass it (which some special sequence of events). Docker or two systems may be better (one handling sensitive information and just the most trusted admins, and an other with everyday tasks)

Comment: How docker can help solve this problem? To meet regulatory requirements we audit every access to the system (with teleport). But I am trying to enforce least privileges principle. Using two different groups of servers can be an answer but it will be costly to use this and meet our operational requirements so we prefer not using it.

Comment: Root can do anything and everything. If a service/daemon can read some data, so can root. Root can read memory contents directly. What you're asking for seems impossible or you don't want the person to be root. If *"granting access"* means `sudo service start/stop` and `sudo vi /etc/service/config` that could work.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I don't want the person to be root, but i want him/her to have some of root privileges. It seems though that doing this properly (filtering root capabilities to achieve the stated goal) is too complicated to be practical.

Comment: What you are looking for is some sort of Access Control structure. Capabilities are override permissions to violate normal access controls. If you want to limit access to config files, can you give those files group write access and give your admins that group membership. If you want to limit privileged access to things, you can create a binary tool that does the things you want to specifically do and grant the admin(s) user or group execute access to those tools. If those tools need capabilities to work, then also give them the specific file capabilities they need.